# checked checkbox answer from a dynamic created checkbox that had ben added to a panel from code behind

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, checkbox, panel, code-behind

i am writing a web page in asp.net, in my aspx page i have a panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server"/>
```

later in my program i add controls (checkbox) to the panel from the code behind.

like the example:

```
if(something)
{
  checkbox cb = new checkbox();
  cb.ID = "checkbox1";
  panel1.Controls.Add(cb);
}
else
{
  checkbox cb = new checkbox();
  cb.ID = "checkbox2";
  panel1.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```

Now my question is:
how can i catch if someone "checked" one of my check box (checkbox1 or checkbox2).
on my panel if the checkbox are created dynamically after the panel is created

thanks

Answer (score 1):

On adding your checkboxes in the code behind you should also assign the associated event for checking/unchecking the CheckBoxes.

```
  CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
  cb.ID = "checkbox1";
  cb.CheckedChanged += Check1_Clicked;
  panel1.Controls.Add(cb);


private void Check1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: This is what i did, but for some reason it does not work, when i click on the checkbocx it does not go to the event i gave it. just to be clear the panel is created when the aspx page is loaded and later in my program i add the check box to the panel controls

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Dimi Toulakis said I think you also need to set the AutoPostBack property of the checkboxes that you add to True.  That way when they are checked or unchecked the page will post back properly.